# Magento keep scroll position when returning on safari

Tags: javascript, magento, magento-1.9

I'm using Magento 1.9.4.0 and on every browser when I click on a products page and then to a product. The scroll position stays the same when returning to the products again. Except for Safari I don't understand why it doesn't work for Safari.

Here is some code I have tried to use but none of these work. I used this code in the Scroll.js file.

```
var Scroll = {
    mainMenuHeight: 0,


    init : function() {
        jQuery('document').ready( function() {
            Scroll.scroll();
            Scroll.anchorClick();
            Scroll.hashOnLoad();
            Scroll.toTop();
        });

        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            // If scroll location cookie is set, and the location is the same
            //scroll to the position saved in the scroll cookie.
            if ( jQuery.cookie("scroll") !== null && jQuery.cookie("location") !== null
                && jQuery.cookie("location") == jQuery(location).attr('href')) {
                jQuery(document).scrollTop( jQuery.cookie("scroll") );
            }

            jQuery("#grid").click(function () {
                // Set cookie with current location
                jQuery.cookie("location", jQuery(location).attr('href'));
                // Set cookie with current scrollposition from the top
                jQuery.cookie("scroll", jQuery(document).scrollTop() );
            });
        });

    },
}
```

And this:

```
var Scroll = {
    mainMenuHeight: 0,

    init: function() {
        jQuery('document').ready(function() {
            Scroll.scroll();
            Scroll.anchorClick();
            Scroll.hashOnLoad();
            Scroll.toTop();
        });
        jQuery(function() {
            var pathName = document.location.pathname;
            window.onbeforeunload = function() {
                var scrollPosition = jQuery(document).scrollTop();
                sessionStorage.setItem("scrollPosition_" + pathName,
                    scrollPosition.toString());
            }
            if (sessionStorage["scrollPosition_" + pathName]) {
                jQuery(document).
                    scrollTop(
                        sessionStorage.getItem("scrollPosition_" + pathName));
            }
        });
    },
}
```

I expected that the scroll position stays the same when returning in Safari too. It works on some products but not on all products...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have managed to fix this myself. It was a file named "slider.js" from scriptaculous. I disabled this file and the issue was gone!